Is the statement, "pursuant Bachelors of Science: Computer Systems Engineering" proper English?
In a resume does it make sense to simply add the word pursuant in front of the degree to indicate that the degree was not obtained?

What did your research into pursuant show? It derives from "following", but doesn't actually mean that.

Using the word “pursuant” in front of a degree on a resume to indicate that the degree was not obtained might not be the best approach, as it could be unclear to some readers. Instead, you can clearly state that the degree is in progress or was not completed. Here are a few ways to present this information:
In Progress: Bachelor of Science in Computer Science (In Progress)
University of XYZ
Expected Completion Date:Bachelor of Science in Computer Science (Expected Graduation: May 2025)
University of XYZ
Credits Earned: Bachelor of Science in Computer Science (Completed 90 credits)
University of XYZ
Incomplete: Bachelor of Science in Computer Science (Incomplete)
University of XYZ
These formats provide clear information about the status of your degree and avoid any potential confusion.
